# CSS Delete div in list

Tags: html, css

I have a list with `<li>`

I want to get a delete div to slide in when a user clicks the X.

I want the red div to be able to grow with its content, and the title text to have ellipsis.

If you look at the example, the first `<li>` is the start result I want, and the second is the end result I want.

[Example](http://jsbin.com/badul/4/edit)

How can I do this?

[Example 2](http://jsbin.com/badul/6/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the *X* and the *Delete* in the same container and then toggle the elements via jQuery:

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <div class="title">
       <div class="actions">X</div>
       <div class="actions2">Delete</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $("li").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).find(".actions").hide();
        }, function() {
            $(this).find(".actions2").show(); //or animate here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/badul/6/edit I tried that but i get problem with the width and need help there.

Comment: Maybe you will have to give a fixed width-value to the <li> and let the <div>s float.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a working example](http://jsbin.com/dosuzuhu/22/) including CSS animations, toggling the Delete button off on escape, and actually removing the parent `<li>` when the delete button is clicked.

I made the action buttons children of the `div.title` and absolutely positioned them in the top right of the `<li>` and adjusted the padding of the `<li>` to allow for the width of the active action button. I also hoisted the `inDeleteMode` class to the `<li>` for better cascading.

Comment: the delete text can be different in different language. Thats why I want it to grow with it content. How can this be solved.

Comment: In that case, I might rather use an icon like a trash can or something that doesn't need translation. If you must use text, then I think you'll need to change everything to use `display: inline;` so that the overflow is handled for you automatically. Then, though, you might have issues getting the right side to line up…